# Java не запускается скомпилированное приложение

Tags: java

Приложение из intellij idea запускается без проблем, но не хочет запускаться из jar (Linux, Windows). Ошибка:

```
java -jar authenticating-ldap.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.webapp.AuthenticatingLdapApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.webapp.AuthenticatingLdapApplication
```

При создании jar в intellij idea, никаких ошибок не возникает. В какую сторону копать?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthenticatingLdapApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthenticatingLdapApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Пишут про параметр CLASSPATH, но я не пойму где он настраивается. Прошу помощи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/18093928/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-Could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: Переименуйте архив в `authenticating-ldap.zip` и распакуйте. Есть ли в архиве папка `com/example/webapp`? Есть ли в этой папке файл `AuthenticatingLdapApplication.class`? Добавьте к вашему вопросу манифест. Без этого никак не ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я по неопытности не упомянул про использование Maven. С ним и компиляция выполняется в другом месте и зависимости дополнительные ставятся. Чуть позже отпишусь.